# Wordpress PHP - Add the_permalink inside a variable then echo

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

I've got this code below that gets a specific category (from a taxonomy) then displays its sub-categories.

I'm trying to figure out how to add a href link to it, linking to the permalink in order to go to the archive page for that particular sub-category. So far I have this:

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( 'job_listing_category', 'parent=59' );
$count = count($terms);
$link_address = the_permalink();

if ( $count > 0 ){

 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
   echo "<a href='".$link_address."'><p>" . $term->name . "</p></a>";

 }


}
?>
```

This line: `echo "<a href='".$link_address."'><p>" . $term->name . "</p></a>";` seems to be correct, however I need to reference the `$link_address` somewhere I assume...

I thought I could get the permalink of the sub-category by adding the line: `$link_address = the_permalink();`

However, this doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why..

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [get term link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/) with get_term_link() and you can pass in the term object. You could do:

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
  echo "<a href='" . get_term_link($term) . "'>" . $term->name . "</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to save the permalink in a variable, you can use get_the_permalink() instead of the_permalink().

Comment: Thanks Leander! I've changed it to get_the_permalink() but it now just seems to link to my homepage for some reason and not an archive page of the sub-category... the code is actually on my homepage if this makes any difference?

Comment: Or is there a way of adding the permalink directly inside the echo statement?